# Difference between args=[topic.id] and args=[topic_id] when using the return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse) in Django

Tags: django, reverse, args

I'm following a tutorial from to build a simple blog app with Django.

I have noticed that in the new_entry() view, we need to pass **topic_id** in agrs when using the reverse function:

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
"""Add a new entry for a particular topic"""
topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

if request.method != 'POST':
    #No data submitted, create a blank form
    form = EntryForm()
else:
    #POST data submitted; process data
    form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
      new_entry.topic = topic
      new_entry.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic_id]))
context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

However, when creating the edit_entry() view (that allows users to edit existing entries), we need to pass **topic.id**

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
"""Edit an existing entry"""
entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
topic = entry.topic

if request.method != 'POST':
    #Initial request, render the form with current entry
    form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
else:
    #Submit changes, process data
    form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic.id]))
context = {'topic':topic, 'entry':entry, 'form':form}
return render(request,'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

Initially I thought this was a mistake so I used args=[topic_id] in both reverse functions and it worked fine

Later, I decided I wanted to add a title to each entry so I made some minor changes to models.py, migrated those changes to the database and then changed the templates to include {{entry.title}} in them.

Basically, all I did was add this code to models.py

title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Add a title')

models.py:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
"""A topic the user is learning about"""
text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model"""
    return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """A blog post about a particular topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Add a title')
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        char_numb = len(self.text)
        if char_numb > 50:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic, Entry


class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text','title']
        labels = {'text':'', 'title': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

After adding these changes, I got the following error when I tried to edit an entry's default title:

NameError at /edit_entry/4/
global name 'topic_id' is not defined

I changed args=[topic_id] to args=[topic.id] in the views.py file edit_entry() view and now it works fine, any idea why this is the case? **What difference is there between topic_id and topic.id in this context?**

This is the edit_entry.html template in case it makes any difference:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1><a href = "{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{topic}}</a>
</h1>

<p>Edit your entry</p>

<form action = "{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}" method 
= 'post'>

        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

    <button name = "submit">save changes</button>

</form>


{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1):

In your first view, you have `topic_id` from the url and you fetch `topic` from the database on the first line, so you can use either `topic_id` or `topic` in the view.

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
```

In the template context for they view, you set `topic` but not `topic_id`. Therefore you can only use `topic.id` in the template.

```
context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
```

In your second view, you get `entry_id` from the url and get `topic` via the entry. You don’t set `topic_id` anywhere so you must use `topic`.

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit an existing entry"""
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
```